# Ubuntu 18.x fixing nvidia screentearing results in custom cursor error

Tags: nvidia, graphics, mouse, themes, cursor-theme

I am using the nvidia proprietary driver. I have fixed the nvidia screentearing by doing:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf

Insert this:

options nvidia_drm modeset=1

Then ctrl+o press enter key ctrl+x to save file and exit.

Then run this command:

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

After applying this however, I get this kind of graphics error when moving a window with the mouse:
[image: Cursor bug]

The interesting thing however is, that it does not happen with all kinds of mouse icons. Examples of mouse icons creating the graphics error is:

- Whiteglass
- Redglass

These mouse icons can be seen under "Gnome Tweaks".

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating nvidia driver